# migrating database back to original database entity framework migrations

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have made some changes to a database using code first entity framework migrations (lets say db2).

I now want to revert the change made back to the original database. As we want to retain the data on the old database (db1) I cant simple clone it.

Can someone please confirm the right process to do this?

I am assuming I will need to perform a rollback on db2 back to the original state it was in when it was cloned from db1.

I would then switch context so I am pointing at db1.

I then add a migration to generate all the database changes.

I then perform update-database to run make the changes.

Is this correct?

I will then need to run a migration to br

Comment: Are you trying to revert and discard changes or are you trying to upgrade a second database to match an updated database? If you want to update, just generate a sql script as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621#script

Comment: Hi Steve, just trying to match the database.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the -Script is for. Here's another link http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `–TargetMigration` parameter in order to migrate to a specific version:

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration: db1
```

[More info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621)